# How to change color of the symbol # in a label's list (Blogger)

Tags: css, label, blogger

how can I change the color of the symbol "#" in a labels'list (blogspot)?
I tried with :first-letter (because it is the first character of the labels'name) but also the first letter results colored.
Thank you

EDIT:
The code is

```
<b:loop values='data:labels where (l =&gt; l.name contains &quot;#&quot; and l.name not contains &quot;#39;&quot;)' var='label'>
    <a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a><br/>
  </b:loop>
```

The jquery that I tried with no results is

```
$('div').each(function () { $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(\#)/g, '<span style="color: #000000;">#</span>')); });
```

Comment: Sophia, It will be easy to understand if can you add the html (at least the lable with symbol and it's parent)?

Comment: Are you limited to CSS, or can you change the HTML, either directly or with JavaScript?

Comment: Hi, I've just edited the question adding the code. I can change the html directly.

Comment: Browsers seem to be inconsistent in their their interpretation of first-letter if that letter is some sort of non alphanumeric. For example, Edge/Chrome treat the first letter of -My string as - but the first letter of #My string as #M FIrefox treats both examples the same giving two characters in both cases. The good news is they seem to be consistent when the first letter is a # and the second alphanumeric, but they all do what you don't want!

Comment: Exactly and so I'm searching to fix this problem with an alternative way but I don't know how.

Comment: Can  you put in some JavaScript or is that not possible?

Comment: It's a style sheet, I tried with a jquery code but it doesn't work. What are you thinking about?

Comment: Seems daft that we could possibly change it to say an emoticon using unicode-range but can't change its color. I'm still thinking - but what jquery did you try, and where did you put it?

Comment: I added the jquery code that I tried

Comment: You are changing the color to #000000 which is black - did you mean #ff0000 which is red? Also, where does this code run? Is there a danger not everything is loaded when it runs? You are replacing in the whole html, could that upset something else that uses #?

Comment: No, I mean exactly black because the label name is colored and I need the hashtag black by contrast. I put this code in a widget html of a blog between <script></script>.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if I'm understanding this correctly, but... "#" is part of the label name, correct?

And ALL labels have the "#" symbol on the name, right?

If so, I'm assuming you can change/edit the label name to remove it... and if that is correct, why not use the CSS ::before Selector to add the "#" symbol and give the color you want?

Something like:

```
.Label ul li a:before {
  content: "#";
  color: #ff0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it because not all labels have the hashtag before the name.